# Store grep within variable and do a sed in bash

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a file with multiple content such as  :

```
Create initial parsimony tree by phylogenetic likelihood library (PLL)... 0.022 seconds
Perform fast likelihood tree search using LG+I+G model...
Estimate model parameters (epsilon = 5.000)
Perform nearest neighbor interchange...
Estimate model parameters (epsilon = 1.000)
1. Initial log-likelihood: -30833.549
Optimal log-likelihood: -30833.420
Proportion of invariable sites: 0.016
Gamma shape alpha: 2.035
Parameters optimization took 1 rounds (0.226 sec)
Time for fast ML tree search: 2.912 seconds
NOTE: ModelFinder requires 64 MB RAM!
ModelFinder will test up to 546 protein models (sample size: 1544) ...
 No. Model         -LnL         df  AIC          AICc         BIC
  1  LG            31317.712    31  62697.424    62698.736    62863.030
  2  LG+I          31170.012    32  62404.024    62405.422    62574.972
  3  LG+G4         30870.402    32  61804.803    61806.201    61975.751
  4  LG+I+G4       30833.404    33  61732.808    61734.294    61909.098
  5  LG+R2         30881.301    33  61828.602    61830.088    62004.892
  6  LG+R3         30831.187    35  61732.374    61734.045    61919.349
Akaike Information Criterion:           VT+F+R4
Corrected Akaike Information Criterion: VT+F+R4
Bayesian Information Criterion:         VT+F+R4
Best-fit model: VT+F+R4 chosen according to BIC
other content....
```

And I would like to store using bash command the element after the part :

```
Bayesian Information Criterion:
```

within a variable called : The_variable.

So far I tried :

```
The_variable="$(grep 'Bayesian Information Criterion:' the_file.txt)"
```

which gives me all the grep line

```
echo $The_variable
Bayesian Information Criterion: VT+F+R4
```

but I would like it to store only the `VT+F+R4` part.

To isolate that part I tried :

```
sed 's@.*: @@g' $VAR
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier in `awk`:

```bash
awk -F ' *: *' '$1 == "Bayesian Information Criterion" {print $2}' file

VT+F+R4

# to save this in a variable:
myvar=$(awk -F ' *: *' '$1 == "Bayesian Information Criterion" {print $2}' file)
```

This `gnu-grep` solution would also work with `\K`:

```bash
grep -oP 'Bayesian Information Criterion:\h*\K.+' file

VT+F+R4
```

Or this `sed`:

```bash
sed -n 's/Bayesian Information Criterion: *//p' file

VT+F+R4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to print what you want. By default the delimiter is space, so `awk '{ print $4 }'` will do the work in your case.

```bash
➜ echo 'Bayesian Information Criterion: VT+F+R4' | awk '{ print $4 }'
VT+F+R4
```